# can we draw shapes (line,circle , etc.) in dialog-based mfc visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, sdi, dialogbasedapp

I want to implement an oscilloscope to display some different frequency via dialog-based MFC visual c++, but as I googling too much , I found out that the only way to drawing shapes in visual c++ is to use SDI or MDI ! 
I want to know if there is a way to drawing my frequency chart by dialog-based mfc.
if anyone know any reference , I really appreciate it if he/she introduce it to me .

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can draw in dialogs with MFC.

In short, drop a "static" (or image, I'm not certain) resource on the dialog, override/derive the class and handle the WM_PAINT message to draw the graph/oscilloscope.

have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/High-speedCharting.aspx  for an excellent example.

Comment: thanks alot Max and thank you for link !
I am very new to windows programming specially to visual c++, can you please explain more about working with static resource . how can I override/derive class?
I am so sorry for my stupid question.
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

you can draw onto anything using [GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can even implement a custom control for your oscilloscope if you plan on reusing it, else you can just use a static/picture frame to act as a container.

for something that can have many updates, like an oscilloscope, you'd probably need to double buffer the surface you draw on, else you'll get tearing. a short overview of using GDI can be found [here](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/gdi.html).

MFC has its own equivalents of the GDI data structures and functions, [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6196kz3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).